# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Aligning Items

Tags: bootstrap-4

I would like the items in my second UL to be aligned to the right of the page. I have tried using mr-auto in the first UL, ml-auto (and ml-md-auto) in the second UL, and justify-content-end but nothing works.

I am having a second issue where the toggle button appears right next to Navbar (found in Navbar) instead of the right of the page.

I was using Colt Steele's Web Dev 'Bootcamp' to learn Bootstrap but they use 3.7 instead of 4 so I'm backtracking unfortunately. I appreciate any and all input.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarText">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the row and now it is working as expected:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarText">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```